# Advanced card payments SDK showing error during submission of form

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-buttons

Error: "Hosted Fields payment is already in progress."

I have copied it from [this PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/), and in the SDK URL pass a proper sandbox clientID.

```
if (paypal.HostedFields.isEligible()) {
       paypal.HostedFields.render({
         createOrder: function () {return "order-ID";}, // replace order-ID with the order ID
         styles: {
           'input': {
             'font-size': '17px',
             'font-family': 'helvetica, tahoma, calibri, sans-serif',
             'color': '#3a3a3a'
           },
           ':focus': {
             'color': 'black'
           }
         },
         fields: {
           number: {
             selector: '#card-number',
             placeholder: 'card number'
           },
           cvv: {
             selector: '#cvv',
             placeholder: 'card security number'
           },
           expirationDate: {
             selector: '#expiration-date',
             placeholder: 'mm/yy'
           }
         }
       }).then(function (hf) {
         $('#my-sample-form').submit(function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           hf.submit({
             // Cardholder Name
             cardholderName: document.getElementById('card-holder-name').value,
             // Billing Address
             billingAddress: {
               streetAddress: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-street').value,      // address_line_1 - street
               extendedAddress: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-unit').value,       // address_line_2 - unit
               region: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-state').value,           // admin_area_1 - state
               locality: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-city').value,          // admin_area_2 - town / city
               postalCode: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-zip').value,           // postal_code - postal_code
               countryCodeAlpha2: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-country').value   // country_code - country
             }
           });
         });
       });
     }
```

Comment: What is your "order-ID" ?

Comment: Order id should be returned from Paypal ?
I have to order first(On paypal via API) before clicking on button you mean?.

Comment: The OrderId is not actually your webiste's order id, it is rather an order id from the PayPal API (/v2/checkout/orders)

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace "order-ID" with an actual PayPal Order ID created for this checkout.

There are several ways to obtain one. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls for how to call the orders API from your server to 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order'. You should use these to create two routes on your server that return only JSON data (no HTML or text)

As for how to fetch and commit this from the JS UI, see  https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server for some demo code.

---

Alternatively, you could try doing an HTML/JS-only integration (no server) like https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: 3rd option you provided pretty good but I want my (Debit and Credit card)form to be open always.